# cognos 11 report chart data labels

Tags: label, report, cognos

I have a clustered column bar chart and I would like the data values to appear on top of the bars. However I do not see any option to show the values on top of the bar.

How does one do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try, but your request is unclear.  Is it a clustered column chart or a clustered bar chart?  Is it a chart, a legacy visualization, or a new visualization?

Assuming you are asking about a clustered column chart:

1. Select the chart.
2. In the data area of the chart, select the *Series* object.
3. Looking at the top of the Properties pane, this is the *Bar*.  You may need to click on the icon, or navigate up from the *Chart node member*.
4. In the Properties pane, under **CHART LABELS**, open the *Show values* property.

If you are looking for this feature for a clustered column visualization -- new or legacy -- I don't see it.  I'd love to know if someone finds it.  Did you ask IBM Support yet?